# Cannot consume my own simple REST API

Tags: java, rest, api, url

So I tried [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_quick_guide.htm) example for setting up a quick rest api. I have followed all the steps and exported a war file and placed it on my tomcat server, which I can reach at my localhost address. The problem I am having is making a GET request to it with Postman. This is how my code looks like:

*ApiResource.java*

```
package main;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/foo")
public class ApiResource {

@GET
@Path("/bar")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String getUsers() {
    return "Testing2";
}
}
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>api-mashup-api</display-name>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.tutorialspoint</param-value>
         </init-param>
      </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And this is the URL I use with postman(it just returns 404, not found. Or rather it returns Tomcats standard error message page for 404, so Tomcat is working.)

```
http://localhost:8080/api-mashup-api/foo/bar
```

Comment: Try this http://localhost:8080/api-mashup-api/rest/foo/bar

Comment: Sadly, that still returns 404. I have tried many different URLS but it doesn't seem to work. Might I have something wrong with my web.xml?

Comment: Is your project name api-mashup-api? If not, you will have to change that too.

Comment: Yes, my project name is api-mashup-api. As I understand the URL should look someting like this:
{<Path to server><display-name in web.xml><URL-pattern in web.xml><path of class><Path of method>}

Comment: No, not the display name but rather the project name. Thus, your URL should look like {<Path to server><project_name_in_IDE><path of class><Path om method>}

Comment: Ok, just like in my post then?

Comment: I don't know. The only thing I see is the display name in web.xml. Check that your project name is api-mashup-api in your IDE. That's because your project gets deployed to a folder having the same name as your project.

Comment: Yes, my project name is "api-mashup-api" I am 100% positive of this. :)

Comment: Can you just do http://localhost:8080 to see if Tomcat is running?

Comment: Your package is com.tutorialspoint as specified in web.xml?

Comment: Yes, Tomcat is running. And yes com.tutorialspoint is my package name. I have also tried just adding a very simple html page in the WebContent folder, which if I got this right, should be shown if I just enter localhost:8080/api-mashup-api/index.html
but it is not shown.

Comment: I think Tomcat will not serve static content (simple HTML,JPG, PDF etc) unless explicitly added in web.xml, so that won't work. Your web.xml seems OK though and your REST should work. Can you check the Firewall settings? Also, you should be running Tomcat 7?

Comment: My firewall settings seems fine. I am actually not sure which version of Tomcat I'm using, I am starting it with XAAMP. However, I think I somehow solved it, not sure why. To reach my html I  can use: http://localhost:8080/api-mashup-api/index.html
And for my api I can use: http://localhost:8080/api-mashup-api/api/foo/bar

Comment: Well, you should've said that Tomcat is behind a web server. That said, I'm not familiar with XAAMP.